# C# Dictionary with two Values per Key?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have a situation in code where a `Dictionary<string, string>` seemed like the best idea - I need a collection of these objects and I need them to be accessible via a unique key. Exactly what the Dictionary concept is for, right?

Well, the requirements have expanded to the point where I now need to hold an additional bit of information per-key (a boolean value, if you're curious).

So, I figure expand the concept to create a new data structure with the string and the boolean and have it now be a `Dictionary<string, NewCustomObject>`.

However, for just one additional value like a boolean flag, it just feels like overkill. And yet I don't know of any Dictionary-like generic object with two values per key.

Is just having a Dictionary of custom objects the best way to go about this or is there something simpler for this scenario?

Comment: The [Multivalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary) dictionary post might serve your needs.

Comment: Your first idea of Dictionary<string, NewCustomObject> is not an overkill at all.  It expresses the exact intent, is strongly-typed, intellisense-enabled, will easily accommodate the next change in requirements.

Comment: @Oren Trutner: Cannot agree more. @Schnapple: Don't bother with a Pair, use a custom object, with well-defined names. Avoid, for example, "Value1" and "Value2" for the field names. Give them semantic meaning.

Comment: There is nothing that approaches 'overkill' when creating new classes in an OO language.  Well, usually there is not, and in this case there is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi value Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary)

Comment: I know it's an old question, but in modern C# you can use [Named Tuples](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+7+named+tuples&oq=c%23+7+named+tuples) as well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Actually, what you've just described is an ideal use for the Dictionary collection. It's supposed to contain key:value pairs, regardless of the type of value. By making the value its own class, you'll be able to extend it easily in the future, should the need arise.

Comment: I wound up going this route as the others looked equally as complicated and it's in .NET 3.5 so no Tuples for me

Answer (score 20):

```
class MappedValue
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, MappedValue> myList = new Dictionary<string, MappedValue>;
```

Answer (score 9):

I think generally you're getting into the concept of Tuples - something like `Tuple<x, y, z>`, or `Tuple<string, bool, value>`.

C# 4.0 will have dynamic support for tuples, but other than that, you need to roll your own or download a Tuple library.

[You can see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169317/what-is-the-collection-equivalent-of-a-multi-dimensional-aray/1169350#1169350) where I put some sample code for a generic tuple class.  Or I can just repost it here:

```
public class Tuple<T, T2, T3>
{
    public Tuple(T first, T2 second, T3 third)

    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
        Third = third;
    }

    public T First { get; set; }
    public T2 Second { get; set; }
    public T3 Third { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

In .NET4, you could use (unchecked): `Dictionary<string, Tuple<bool,string>>`

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe .net has Multi-Map built in which is generally a data-structure you can use to do this type of storage.  On the other hand I don't think it's overkill at all just using a custom object that holds both a string and a boolean.

Comment: Multi-maps let you store multiple values against a given key, but the values are of the same type and are not otherwise distinguished, so that would not fit this need.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work for ya?

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Or you could use a [Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099134/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-two-lists-in-c/1099154#1099154) and have a dictionary of that:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, bool>>
```

Comment: So how does he store the boolean with this?

Comment: Or equivalently, `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`.

Comment: Ralph: I answered the title initially. Added a solution for that case.

Comment: Steve: `NameValueCollection` is not a hash table. It performs `O(n)` searches.

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary is just a keyed collection of objects. As such, it will hold any type of object you want. Even the simplest of objects, like, say, an *array* (which derives from Object), but requires a lot less code on your behalf.

Rather than writing an entire class, stuff a dynamically allocated array, or a List in the value and run with that.

Dictionaries are highly flexible that way.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class?

**Edit:**

After read the question carefully think this is not the best solution, but it still a good one for the dictionary with some values per a single key.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to store the boolean in a separate data structure, e.g. a HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

Tuple is always a good solution. Furthermore in an object oriented approach, always favour composition over inheritance. Construct a composite object doing the grouping. Simply. I think you are covered with some nice and clean solutions here, from fellow stackoverflow'ers. :)