# Return KeyValuePair or use out variable in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a function that needs to return two strings. I've considered two different ways to do this:

```
string first = "this is first";
string second = "this is second";
KeyValuePair<string, string> ReturnPair()
{
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(first, second);
}
string ReturnOne(out string other)
{
    other = second;
    return first;
}
```

I would like to use the KeyValuePair<> approach but I feel that I am misusing the purpose for which this object was created.

My questions:

1. Is there a better way to return 2 strings in this example?
2. Is there anything wrong with returning the KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While there's nothing *technically* wrong with returning `KeyValuePair`, the thing you are returning is not *conceptually* a "key-value" pair. It's a simple pair.

Alternatively you can use a `Tuple`, which is available in .NET 4.0 or in the meantime, declare [your own structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099134/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-two-lists-in-c/1099154#1099154).

I normally advice against `out` parameters for returning tuples. Specially when you are using LINQ and functional language constructs, working with `out` parameters is tedious.

Comment: Correct, the thing that I'm returning is NOT a KeyValuePair and that's why I'm hesitant in using that construct. The thing is a Tuple. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 6):

If the data belongs logically together, but one is not logically the key of the other, I would define a new type that encapsulates it.

If one is a key to the other, I would use NameValuePair.

Comment: I was going to say this, too.   If, for example, you're representing a person's two names, you could have a class with a FirstName and LastName property.  This opens up the possibility of creating a FullName getter in the future.

Answer (score 6):

This would be my preferred method. KeyValuePair is so verbose.

```
String[] ReturnPair()
{
    return new [] { first, second };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion would be

```
void ReturnTwo(out string one, out string two)
{
  // do assignments
}
```

I feel this makes it more explicit on what the return values are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of the multiple output parms. Nor do I like using a key value pair if the first string is not truly a key. My suggestion would be to return **List<string>**. This will provide a flexible and stable signature. For example if you later decide you want to return 3 or 4 strings you can just update the logic inside the method without monkeying with the signature.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question with a variety of answers: [How do you return two values from a single method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468375/how-do-you-return-two-values-from-a-single-method/1468525)

From the "clean-code" perspective, using "out" parameters to return these two strings is bad. Assuming you don't have time to refactor/clean up your design, the solution proposed by John Kraft is definitely acceptable.